# Mountain Lion email share option opens a secondary Mail application

Tags: macos, mail.app, email

I am having a weird issue when I use the share functionality baked into Mountain Lion. Whenever I have a file highlighted in finder and choose the email option to share a file with someone, it decides to "re-open" Mail. Now this is a problem for two reasons. One, having to start Mail up is an unnecessary waste of time if its already open (I always leave Mail running in a side space), and two, some of my accounts wont refresh because there are two simultaneous connections.

Here is a screenshot to better illustrate what is happening:

I select the file, hit share and chose email.

[image: select file and share]

A second Mail app opens and begins to launch displaying the compose box (with the file attached)

[image: mail is open twice]

It is also visible twice in mission control:

[image: mail open twice in mission control]
As you can see, Mail is open and running twice. Does anyone know why this is happening? It would be nice to find a way to prevent it.

Comment: Just for clarification, "Whenever I chose the email option to share a file with someone" ? are we talking about simple attaching the file or ?

Comment: I edited the post to clarify. As in when having a file highlighted in finder, hitting the share button, and choosing email

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I m not solving your problem but sharing.I use Outlook. But I hate it to have to open the mail first than go and select what I wanted to send. So I made a little Automator action that allows me to RIGHT click on the file I want to send (in Finder) and it opens a Mail window ect...

Comment: Me again :) what is that Error showing partially on your screen about Mail ? something about configure your Mail...

Comment: Does this happen within other user? Without spaces?

Comment: I have a similar thing happening to the Messages app on OS X. When I get an iMessage, it opens up the app twice, so the messages.app that I kept on the Dock and another one open up. When I quit one, only one quits, but if I right-click and tell it to show in Finder, it shows the same Messages.app in the Applications folder for both. I don't seem to remember there being an update for the messages app so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation for this is that you have at least two versions of Mail installed (for whatever reason). Your system default mail application happens to be the old version.

When an application uses the sharing API on ML to write an email, it is opened in the default system mail application. This setting, strangely enough, is inside Mail's preferences (not System Preferences).

Under the *General* tab is an item called *Default mail reader*, which is your system default.

In your preferred version of Mail, Open *Mail* -> *About Mail*, and note the version. Now select that version of Mail in Mail's preferences for *Default email reader*.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't attach images.

Comment: If you post links to images hosted on another site, you can flag the post and a mod (or high-rep user) can edit the images in.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem, but I do NOT have two copies of the mail app. When it happens, it shows up twice in the dock, but if I right-click the dock icon and choose "Options -> Show in Finder" they both show the same "Mail" icon in my applications folder.